# How to remove NAs from categorical data?

Tags: r, missing-data

My data goes like this:

```
survey <- data.frame("Death" = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 0,1,NA,0,1,0),
                     "recover" = c(0, 0, 0, NA, 1,NA,0,1,0,NA))
```

My desired output is to replace `NAs` with the same data from the similar column.

I have tried mutations, but the answer is not coming correctly.

Comment: but replace with what? NA to `??`

Comment: NAs to same data , according to the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R we could use `complete.cases` to get cases without `NA`

```
survey_complete <- complete.cases(survey)
survey[survey_complete,]
```

Output:

```
> survey[survey_complete,]
  Death recover
1     1       0
2     1       0
3     1       0
5     0       1
8     0       1
9     1       0
```